# Self-Hosted IR security concerns

Tags: azure-data-factory

..Hi all, in my team we have to install an Integration Runtime and they are having some security concerns about what ports are opened. Which ones are needed? Also, if they have a VPN, do they have to include the Azure subscription into it?

Comment: For ports, I suggest you read the doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#ports-and-firewall. They don't have to use their VPN to communicate between on-premises and Azure but it would make sense to use a dedicated link for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I set up a dedicated link? ExpressRoute?

Comment: You can use a VPN or ExpressRoute to set up a dedicated link. This is not a simple question that can be answered in a site like this. There's a whole host of network architecture questions to be understood and answered. There needs to be an understanding of cost vs security requirements. If you have network people you need to ask them. If you are the network person, you have some reading to do

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, I'm definitely not the network person. I have scaled the case so our network admins can take care of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the documentation I use everytime when a client has security questions about the self hosted IR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

About the VPN issue, there is no need to include anything on the VPN as far as the required ports are opened (443 for blob storage, 1433 if using a SQL Server in the cloud).

Hope this helped!